# Can I respond with XML to an HTML request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rendering

I want to put in a simple API that responds to a GET request with a query string. But I want to return XML, not HTML.

I would even like to test this in the browser so that if I key in the URL and the query string, then see the XML in the response.

I just about have it by rendering `:text`, but my xml is doing two things:

```
1. All tag names are being downcased.

2. My xml is being wrapped in an HTML container (HTML, HEAD, BODY, etc.)
```

I just need to get rid of that HTML wrapper.

Comment: Do you have a layout set for this action? Maybe `:layout => false` would do the trick.

Comment: ```layout: false``` is still giving me the wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml do
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="katalog.xml"'
    render :xml => xml_array.to_xml(:skip_types => true, :root => "Items"),
           :layout => false,
           :content_type => Mime::XML
  end
end
```

You should be able to replace `xml_array.to_xml(:skip_types => true, :root => "Items")` with your string, since .to_xml doesn't do anything else but generating a string (and making sure it's proper XML)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply render as xml (in your controller) with:

```
render xml: @your_object
```

Comment: I'm building the XML string from scratch, so I don't want anything automatic done for me.

Comment: Oh, OK. Anyway, rendering as :text should not modify your string in any way, also it shouldn't add wrappers. I just tried and can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Oktav you were right, it was Firebug that was adding the wrapper. When I looked at the raw source it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

layout false, only: [:action]

This will remove all layout associated code.

Answer (score 0):

On rails 5.2.x this is how you do it

```rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def view
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render formats: [:xml]
  end
end
```

With its corresponding view on app/views/user/view.xml

```xml
xml.User do
  xml.name @user.name
end
```